# .htaccess redirect if ANY query string is present?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess at present.

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
 suPHP_ConfigPath /home/abc/php.ini
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Está dominado!!"
AuthUserFile "/home/abc/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Now the thing is, I would like to, if any query string is found after a / remove that query string.

So: 
If we have:

> **http://www.abc.com/**?somethinghere234

It should redirect to:

> **http://www.abc.com/**

If we have:

> **htpp://www.abc.com/something/**?id212

Redirect to:

> **htpp://www.abc.com/something/**

UPDATE:
I've tried this:

**TRY A)**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php/ [L,QSA]
```

Hopping that  ^(.*)$ will allow anything on the query string...

I've also tried this:

**TRY B)**

> RewriteEngine on RewriteCond $1
>   !^(index.php|media|css|js|images|robots.txt)
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/ [L]

This returns a 500 internal server error.

**TRY C)**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/ [R=302,L]
```

I confess I'm kind of lost on this .htaccess sintax.

**TRY D)**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Please advice,
MEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.php/? [L]
```

1. check if you've got something in QUERY_STRING (yours also accepts an empty string)
2. your check to prevent endless redirect
3. redirect to wherever you want.

From the Apache documentation:

> When you want to erase an existing
>   query string, end the substitution
>   string with just a question mark

**EDIT (again):** As external redirect (you may not even need the second RewriteCond if you don't have any query string at all in your application):

This will tell the client to request the same URI without query string.

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to same URI, but without query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301]

# CodeIgniter "magic"
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @icanhasserver - That returns a 404 error when I put a query string. :( No luck then.

Comment: You have to match the RewriteRule to the actual location of your PHP script. The trailing / may not necessarily either. Hard to say without knowing your setup. If it's located on the same level as the .htaccess file: index.php?

Comment: Thanks. I'm over CodeIgniter if this matters, but yes, the index.php file is on the same level as the .htaccess file. At the first .htaccess (posted above) I have this rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] and it works on that case.

Comment: See my edit, as you added some examples later on. This version may better suite your needs (use the second RewriteCond to filter any require a query string).

Comment: That will almost work. If I put: http://www.abc.com/?something I DO GET redirected. However, if I put http://www.abc.com/somecontroller/ I get a The requested URL /somecontroller was not found on this server. and a 404

Comment: One more edit. It looks like you removed the CodeIgniter rules from your .htaccess?

Comment: AFK - Thanks a lot I will test it once I get the chance and post back the results.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure from your description exactly what you were after, so you should keep or remove the second RewriteCond depending on your specific needs.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove the query string with a redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_SRING} !=""
# But only if the path ended with a /
# (remove this to redirect anything with a query string)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule .* /$0? [R=301,L]

# Then perform your internal rewrite
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Almost, so I believe. I get a 404 when I try the internal redirect. But, if I change, on the last RewriteRule to something like: http://somexternalsite.com/$1 [L] it will work. :(

Comment: @MEM It's possible that Apache isn't liking your internal rewrite with PATH_INFO. You can try adding `AcceptPathInfo On` to your .htaccess file, or remove the `/$1` in the second RewriteRule and change `$config['uri_protocol']` to `REQUEST_URI` in your CodeIgniter configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. I have uri_protocol set to request_uri it will be a question of testing the AcceptPathInfo On and remove the condition call /$1. I'm AFK - once I get back to it, I will post back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MEM: Ah, if you already have it set to `REQUEST_URI` then it's best to get rid of the `/$1` part anyway as it's unnecessary. CodeIgniter will just disregard the PATH_INFO portion it provides in favour of looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you have **QSA** added on there - it means **Query String Append**.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)([^/]+)$
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]
```