# htacess redirect if url stops with specific word

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect based on an url that would be as:

www.url.com/stuff.php

But not redirect if the url contained any characters after the php, as such:

www.url.com/stuff.php?variables=values&othervariable=othervalue&etc=more

I have no clue how to wriite this either.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: basically I need the redirect to happen to www.url2.com only if www.url.com ends with .php, but not if the .php is followed by variables.

Comment: pls clarify some more about what u need

Comment: I need to know how to write this in htacess, please and thank you!

Comment: you're redirecting to another page on your server, or to external server?

Comment: The redirect is on the same server

Comment: learn the logic from this question  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227497/htaccess-redirect-if-any-query-string-is-present

Answer (score 1):

try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/site.com/?$   /site.com/cart.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: on which url you want to redirect the `stuff.php` ?

Comment: The original url is http://site.com/cart.php the redirect would go to http://site.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?cart.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^stuff.php$ RELATIVE_OR_ABSOLUTE_URL_HERE [L]
```

Comment: This works ish but redirects all the links, so if I have stuff.php?variable=value it still redirects

Comment: This works: 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/billing/cart.php$ http://site.com/ 
but like I said it doesn't stop with cart.php